# WTForms Validation Error on ListField

Tags: python, validation, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm getting the following error

ValidationError: ValidationError(Value must be one of ['AL','CT', 'DE', 'FL'... 'WY']: ['state'])

but what I can't seem to figure out why it's validating that field at all when I have in my models;

```
class User(mongoengine.Document): 

    username = mongoengine.StringField(unique=True, max_length=30, required=True,verbose_name="Pick a Username") 
    state = mongoengine.ListField(required=False, verbose_name="State", choices=[('AL' , 'Alabama'), ('AK' , 'Alaska') ,('AZ' , 'Arizona'), ('AR' , 'Arkansas') ,('CA' , 'California'), ('CO' , 'Colorado') ,('CT' , 'Connecticut'), ('DE' , 'Delaware') ,('FL' , 'Florida')...('WY' , 'Wyoming')]) 

user_form = model_form(User, exclude=['password','name','address','address2','zipcode','state']) 
signup_form = model_form(User, exclude=['name','address','address2','zipcode','state'])
```

I'm at a loss, because I though the at first the require=false meant it would be ignored,and secondly the exclude also made me think it should be ignored.  Why is this validation error still happening (outside than the fact that I'm not filling it out in the form)? For more context the full model.py and app.py can be found here

https://github.com/markbreneman/TroubleShooting/tree/master/SecondNatureWebsite

Answer (score 1):

`required=False` means user has no obligation to input at least 1 datum into that field.
maybe the choices from your input form and the field's predefined choices aren't matched.

Comment: Okay, I can look into that but that still doesn't answer why its included in the form when i have, exclude state in the form.

Comment: I love that you use datum for that 1 entity ;)